# flutter: how to downgrade flutter beta channel version

Tags: flutter, sdk, version

In order to create a flutter web app, I used the command `flutter channel beta` and `flutter upgrade`. The result is that my flutter beta channel version is now 2.1.0-12.2.pre, but my flutter stable channel version remains 1.22.4. The problem is that when I open my flutter android app in beta channel, all my files have errors because of null safety change. So I wanted to downgrade my flutter beta channel by using command `flutter downgrade v1.26.0-17.8.pre`, but terminal says  `There is no previously recorded version for channel 'beta'`. How can I downgrade my flutter beta channel to v1.26.0-17.8.pre in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter Version Management CLI (fvm) for this. Besides, you can install any Flutter version you want, and switch between them.

Just run `fvm use` and select a Flutter version you want to use. You can find the documentation on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm)